# How to populate DropDownList in asp with enum possible values from a MySQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my MySQL Database I have a column of type enum with predefined values. 
The column's name is Category and the values are 'movie','gaming', 'food', ... and so on. And now in my aspx page, there's a asp DropDownList that I would like to populate with the enum possible values.

So In my code behind I would like to get these possible values and populate my DropDownList with them

I would like if you you guys would lead me to the right path, thank you very much!

Comment: Haven't you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the data directly from the database and add the ListItems to the DropDownList.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Insert(i, new ListItem(reader["Text"].ToString(), reader["Valye"].ToString(), true));
    i++;
}
```

Or you can bind an already exisiting source that has been populated somewhere else

```
DataTable source = new DataTable();

List<myClass> source = new List<myClass>();

DropDownList1.DataSource = source;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Text";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Value";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Or use an `SqlDataSource`

```
SqlDataSource source = new SqlDataSource();
source.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM yourTable";
source.ConnectionString = Common.connectionString;

DropDownList1.DataSource = source;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Text";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Value";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```